# Can I add one socket to multiple epoll instance?

Tags: c++, reactjs, loops, sockets, networking

I will work on a network design which is using React pattern. In order to have great scalability, I make the design works as one loop per thread. The loop is an abstraction of Linux epoll then I can add socket to the loop.

I can also start multiple threads which each thread has its own loop. But I have a question is can I add a same socket (either listening socket or connection socket) to multiple loops? My feeling is impossible. Otherwise, when the socket get the packet or it is writable, which loop it should trigger when execute epoll_wait() ?

If adding one socket multiple loops is not feasible, but my application is working on a high request volume server which there are large number of requests for the same socket, one thread may not be enough. In this case, how can I improve the performance of my program except increasing the hardware performance ? Depolying the application to multiple servers ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can, and it's simply unpredictable which one will be triggered.

Comment: See https://idea.popcount.org/2017-02-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-12/ for pitfalls of multiple threads polling the same FD.

Comment: Thanks for link. But I think the case you mentioned is different : "have one epoll set and use multiple threads to pull active sockets and perform the work". This is multiple threads to pull from one single epoll. So my understanding is the socket is only added into one epoll in this case.

Comment: I don't think that difference is significant.

Comment: You can find many other sites if you google "epoll multiple threads"

Comment: I have tested by myself. There is no problem to add the same listening socket to multiple epoll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try EPOLLONESHOT, maybe one epoll set is for read and the other is for write~